# UILocalNotification and iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, audio, notifications, local, alert

guys :)
I'm using local notification in my application and I provide action for the UILocalNotification so that the user can open the application when the notification fires. I'm pretty sure that before iOS 4.2, when the user taps the action button, the alert sound was stopped immediately. But when I run my application on iOS 4.2 simulator, the sound plays until it reaches its end, which is very bad for me, because the sound file is pretty long - around 30 seconds. I don't want to shorten the alert sound, because it's an alarm application. But if the user clicks the "Close" button of the local notification alert view, the sound is stopped at the very same moment. Do you know if there is any workaround to stop the alarm sound when the user clicks the action button? Huge thanks in advance, I'm really looking forward for your advices. Happy coding :)

Comment: Why not create repeating local notifs until the application launches?

Comment: Hello, Richard :) Sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you mean... How will repeating local notifications help me in this situation? Thank you for the quick response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 4.2 (and not just in the simulator).  I can't find any way to cancel a sound in mid-playback, as canceling the notification doesn't do it.

Comment: Hello, cetcet :) I tested the application on iPad with iOS 4.2 and it worked as expected. I don't have an access to an iPhone with iOS 4.2, but I hope it will work on it too. Let's hope it's just a bug in the simulator ;)

Comment: Hmmm... well, sounds have never worked reliably on the simulator for me, so I only rely on the device for sound testing.  That said, the problem described above is 100% repeatable for me, but only for sound-only notifications (no message body), and only when the phone is unlocked.  Sound-only notifications that occur when the phone is locked do stop when I 'slide to unlock.'  Anyone else had this problem, or have a suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

I stabbing in the dark on this one, but can you play a "silent" sound when the user clicks the action button? Thereby overriding the currently playing sound?